# How to get all the URLs in a web site using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

Any one knows a way to get all the URLs in a website using JavaScript?

I only need the links starting with the same domain name.no need to consider other links.

Comment: Define "all the URLs". Do you mean `<a>` tags? Or any string content that fits the scheme of a URL?

Comment: the href attribute inside <a> tags

Answer (score 22):

Well this will get all the same-host links on the *page*:

```
var urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href);
```

If by *site* you mean you want to recursively get the links inside linked pages, that's a bit trickier. You'd have to download each link into a new document (for example in an `<iframe>`), and the `onload` check the iframe's own document for more links to add to the list to fetch. You'd need to keep a lookup of what URLs you'd already spidered to avoid fetching the same document twice. It probably wouldn't be very fast.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't decide whether to use a object like a set or just an array. You'd definitely want the set-like once you start crawling multiple pages and need to look up whether the URL had been done before.

Comment: so then that means i have to load each page in the website right?and by the way how can i not show those loading pages to the user?

Comment: Yes. You can load the pages into a hidden `<iframe>`.

Comment: @bobince : why do you use `===`instead of `==`?

Comment: @user2284570: It's generally a good habit as the JavaScript `==` operator is [wonky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).

Answer (score 11):

Or in es6

```js
[...document.links].map(l => l.href)
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript to extract (and display) the domains, urls, and links from a page
The "for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;)" method is a good collection to work with. Here is a example to pulls it from specific parts of the html page.

You could alter it to select and filter to whatever you want. And then use the list however you want. I wanted to show a working example.

```js
var re = /^((http[s]?|ftp|mailto):(?:\/\/)?)?\/?(([^\/\.]+\.)*?([^\/\.]+\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,4})?(\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,2})?(:\d+)?)($|\/)([^#?\s]+)?(.*?)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/i;
var reG = /^((http[s]?|ftp|mailto):(?:\/\/)?)?\/?(([^\/\.]+\.)*?([^\/\.]+\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,4})?(\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,2})?(:\d+)?)($|\/)([^#?\s]+)?(.*?)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/ig;
var printList = document.getElementById("domains");
var unorderedList =  document.createElement("ul");
unorderedList.setAttribute("id", "domainsList");
unorderedList.setAttribute("class", "list-group");
printList.appendChild(unorderedList);
var domainsList = document.getElementById("domainsList");


var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
//console.log(list);
var listArray = Array.from(list);

//loop through the list
listArray.forEach(function(link){
 //console.log(link.href);
  //console.log(typeof(link.href));

var listItem =  document.createElement("li");
listItem.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item domain"); 
domainsList.appendChild(listItem);
  var str = link.href;
  var match = str.match(reG);
  var matchGroup = str.match(re);
  //console.log(matchGroup[5]);
  var domainNode = document.createTextNode("Domain: " + matchGroup[5]);
  listItem.appendChild(domainNode);
  var breakNode  =  document.createElement("br");
  listItem.appendChild(breakNode);
  var websiteNode = document.createTextNode("Website: " + matchGroup[3]);
  listItem.appendChild(websiteNode);
  var breakNode  =  document.createElement("br");
  listItem.appendChild(breakNode);
  var fullNode = document.createTextNode("Full Link: " + match);
  listItem.appendChild(fullNode);
  domainsList.appendChild(listItem);
  unorderedList.appendChild(listItem)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Pull Domains form a page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="card-deck">
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9B_1Ac5jnc">Link 1</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://www.apple.com">Link 2</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://www.cnn.com.au">Link 3</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://downloads.news.com.au">Link 4</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://ftp.android.co.nz">Link 5</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://global.news.ca">Link 6</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="https://www.apple.com">Link 7</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="https://mira.mx/">Link 8</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://www.qs.com/">Link 9</a></div></div>
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 10rem;"><div class="card-body"><a href="http://pbs.org">Link 10</a></div></div>
</div>

<div id="domains"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle of a working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/cgjerdingen/e2y6dhzr)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
(function(){
    let links = [], l = document.links;
    for(let i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
        links.push(l[i].href);
    }
    return links;
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

using jquery u can find all the links on the page that match a specific criteria

```
$("a[href=^domain.com]").each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```